# Erro: subquery retornando mais de um resultado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dado o sql:

```
DELETE FROM wgcartarmazens
 WHERE (
   SELECT artigo 
     FROM wgcartarmazens as T 
    INNER JOIN wgcartigos as A ON A.CODIGO=T.ARTIGO
    WHERE T.lote='' AND A.TEMLOTE<>0
 );
```

A query acima me retorna o seguinte erro

> subquery returns more than 1 value this is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows

Como posso corrigir?

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer fazer um DELETE em todos os campos da subquery, faça assim:

```
DELETE FROM wgcartarmazens
 WHERE artigo IN (
   SELECT artigo 
     FROM wgcartarmazens as T 
     JOIN wgcartigos as A ON A.CODIGO = T.ARTIGO
    WHERE T.lote = ''
      AND A.TEMLOTE <> 0
 );
```

Comment: @user2478690 nossas respostas são praticamente iguais, mas não se trata de oportunismo. Só vi seu comentário depois de editar a pergunta e postar a resposta.